# AngularJs auth service behaves strangely

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, coffeescript, angular-services

*Updated*: [code in JS](https://gist.github.com/zishe/6972512)

I borrowed auth (session) service from [angular-app](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app), and strongly modify it:

```
  angular.module('auth', [])
    .factory('session', ['$location', '$http', '$q', ($location, $http, $q) ->

      service =

        requestCurrentUser: ->
          if service.isAuthenticated()
            $q.when service.currentUser
          else
            $http.get('/user').then (response) ->
              console.log(response.data)
              service.currentUser = response.data
              service.currentUser

        currentUser: null

        isAuthenticated: ->
          not service.currentUser?

      service
    ])
```

This is an app:

```
  BookReader = angular.module('BookReader', ['ngRoute', 'home', 'main', 'books', 'auth'])

  BookReader
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) ->
      $routeProvider
        .when '/',
          templateUrl: 'assets/tour.html'
          controller: 'MainCtrl'
        .when '/home',
          templateUrl: 'assets/main.html'
          controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        .when '/books',
          templateUrl: 'assets/books.html'
          controller: 'BooksCtrl'
    ])
    .run(['session', (session) ->
      session.requestCurrentUser()
    ])
```

So, i guess, when the application starts the currentUser is requested (perhaps a controller starts working before the callback of the request, but the problem in other place). Next, Controllers:

```
angular.module('main', ['ngCookies'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$cookies', '$location', 'session', '$log',
    ($scope, $http, $cookies, $location, session, $log) ->
      $log.info "currentUser: " + session.currentUser + " ; isAuth: " + session.isAuthenticated()
      $location.path '/home' if session.isAuthenticated()
  ])


angular.module('home', ['ngCookies'])
  .controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$cookies', 'session', '$location', '$log'
    ($scope, $http, $cookies, session, $location, $log) ->
      $log.info "currentUser: " + session.currentUser + " ; isAuth: " + session.isAuthenticated()
      $location.path '/' unless session.isAuthenticated()
  ])
```

The point is that `isAuthenticated()` always `false`, but `currentUser` not null when a user is logged in. So, when i logged in `$log.info` shows `currentUser: [object Object] ; isAuth: false` and not only when the site just loaded, but when i'm navigating too. When i logged out it shows `currentUser: null ; isAuth: false`. Obviously, `currentUser` is always null inside the service. But how can i define it to be able change the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a watch function:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
   return session.isAuthenticated();
 },
 function() {
   $log.info "currentUser: " + session.currentUser + " ; isAuth: " + session.isAuthenticated()
 }
);
```

Comment: I just figured out that there is no need in that method `isAuthenticated` if i have correctly works current_user. That was so obvious and i didin't see that! Thanks for help =)

Comment: I don't know what i did, but i was sure it works, but now it doesn't with the same code.

Answer (score 1):

update isAuthenticated to

```
isAuthenticated: ->
      service.currentUser?
```

although this is async you should use resolve in router.

Comment: `isAuthenticated` `true` all the time, in controller. Probably this asynchrony is the reason of this behaviour. I'm trying to perform resolve, but it wont access to session in the router. `Unknown provider: session` but it is undoubtedly included. http://pastebin.com/UjmHEz2T

Comment: Perhaps i can do this method synchronous. I'm not good at resolve, by the way=) I should maybe create promise.